# maximum length of a field name in JSON

Tags: json

What is the maximum length of a field name in JSON?

For example, in the following json document

```
{
    "myfield":"value"
}
```

can I make "myfield" as long as 100 characters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the limit on the length of a javascript property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628501/what-is-the-limit-on-the-length-of-a-javascript-property)

Comment: um, try it and find otu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON is a format like XML and it doesn't have any limits. However, the JSON parser may impose a limit on the size of the document as a whole:

- in ASP.Net, there's "MaxJsonLength". The default is 2097152 characters, which is equivalent to 4 MB of Unicode string data.
- in PHP, there's no max length for a JSON string. PHP will fail parsing a JSON string if it reaches the PHP `memory_limit` or if the JSON string posted is larger than the PHP `post_max_size`.
- etc.

A hundred characters won't cause a problem. If you reach 4MB of data, you should probably look into reducing the size of the JSON document or finding a workaround.

**EDIT**

To clarify my point, there's no limit for a name or value inside a JSON document. If there's any limit, it is applied to the size of the JSON document as a whole.

Comment: This is related to the `JSON` string length as a whole, and not regarding the object property length that's serialized.

Comment: Yep because there's no limit for a JSON value inside a JSON string. The limit is applied to the JSON string as a whole.