# Google Apps Script - Label Email Based On Email Body [Optimize Code]

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, gmail-api

I aim to do the following:

- An email is received that matches the criteria be placed in Label A folder.
- A new email is received.
- This new email's body is a duplicate of the first received.
- This new email skips the inbox and goes to Label B folder.

Here is how I implemented it:

- All new emails are labeled as "Original"
- When the script runs, it compares the email body with all previous ones.
- If the body is a duplicate, it is labeled "Duplicate", moved to "Archive" and "Original" label is removed.

The code is as follow:

```
function emailLabeling() {


var DUPLICATE = _getLabel();
  var labels = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Original");
  if(labels != null){
    var threads = labels.getThreads();
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++){
      var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
      for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++){
        var message = messages[j];
        for (var k = i; k < threads.length; k++){
        var messages_check = threads[k].getMessages();
          for (var l = j; l < messages_check.length; l++){
            var message_check = messages_check[l];
            if(message_check.getPlainBody() == message.getPlainBody()){
              if(i !=  k || j != l){
                Logger.log(i +""+ j +""+ k +""+ l);
                DUPLICATE.addToThread(threads[i]);
                labels.removeFromThread(threads[i]);
                GmailApp.moveThreadToArchive(threads[i]);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  else{
    Logger.log("Label Not Found!");
  }
}

function _getLabel() {
  var label_text = "Duplicates";
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label_text);
  if (label == null) {
    var label = GmailApp.createLabel(label_text);
  }
  return label;
}
```

The code works fine. The problem lies in 4 nested loop, which exponentially increases the runtime as the number of "Original" emails increase.

**Is there a way to optimize this code?**
**Is there a smarter logic to implement this idea?**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that even after you start looking at a new thread, you keep starting your message_checks after the `j`th message in that thread, rather than 0. This means you're skipping email checks. Also, It isn't really clear what you do when you find a duplicated body - I would have kept the earlier thread - `i` - in the label and moved the later thread - `k` - to the `"duplicate"` label (you would have to check that the label is still present for non-zero `i` somehow).

Comment: you are right it should start from 0.  And the aim was to move the latest thread. I guess this code is buggy. :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method of improving performance in nested loop situations - especially duplicate identification - is to store a record of traversed content, rather than repeatedly comparing. For example, you could [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) the message body (given the right hash function) and store the hashes as object properties. Note that there is no [formal limit on the length of an object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628501/what-is-the-limit-on-the-length-of-a-javascript-property) so you may be able to skip hashing it yourself (to obtain a fixed length property) and just let Google Apps Script do it for you. It's probably wise to test how large a message can be before using such an assumption in production, naturally.

```
function updateEmailLabels() {
  // Use an Object to associate a message's plaintext body with the
  // associated thread/message IDs (or other data as desired).
  var seenBodies = {}, // When a message is read, its plaintext body is stored.
      DUPLICATE = _getLabel("SO_Duplicates"),
      ORIGINAL = _getLabel("SO_Original");

  // getThreads() returns newest first. Start with the oldest by reversing it.
  ORIGINAL.getThreads().reverse().forEach(function (thread) {
    thread.getMessages().forEach(function (message, messageIndex) {
      // Use this message's body for fast lookups.
      // Assumption: Apps Script has no reachable limit on Object property length.
      var body = message.getPlainBody();

      // Compare this message to all previously seen messages:
      if (!seenBodies[body]) {
        seenBodies[body] = {
          count: 1,
          msgIndices: [ messageIndex ],
          threads: [ thread ],
          threadIds: [ thread.getId() ]
        };
      } else {
        // This exact message body has been observed previously.
        // Update information about where the body has been seen (or perform
        // more intricate checks, i.e. compare threadIds and message indices,
        // before treating this thread and message as a duplicate).
        seenBodies[body].count += 1;
        seenBodies[body].msgIndices.push(messageIndex);
        seenBodies[body].threads.push(thread);
        seenBodies[body].threadIds.push(thread.getId());
      }
    }); // End for-each-message. 
  }); // End for-each-thread.

  // All messages in all threads have now been read and checked against each other.
  // Determine the unique threads to be modified.
  var threadsToChange = {};
  for (var body in seenBodies) {
    if (seenBodies[body].count === 1)
      continue;
    var data = seenBodies[body];
    for (var threadIndex = 1; threadIndex < data.threads.length; ++threadIndex)
      threadsToChange[data.threadIds[threadIndex]] = data.threads[threadIndex];
  }
  // Update their labels and archive status.
  for (var id in threadsToChange) {
    var thread = threadsToChange[id];
    DUPLICATE.addToThread(thread);
    ORIGINAL.removeFromThread(thread);
    GmailApp.moveThreadToArchive(thread);
  }
}

function _getLabel(labelText) {
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(labelText);
  return label ? label : GmailApp.createLabel(labelText);
}
```

You'll definitely want to tweak the duplicate detection bits, since I don't exactly have qualifying emails just laying around ;) I suspect what I've written will classify a thread as duplicate if at least 2 messages are the same, even if that thread is the only thread with that particular message body.