# Checking to see if a value exists anywhere in an array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a script that looks at one sheet ("Data") and from a column of dates finds dates that are 3 months in the future and copies those rows into another sheet ("3 Months"). It can do that, Yay!

What I'd also like it to do is check on the "3 Months" sheet for a unique ID on each row and if that Unique ID exists, then don't copy that row from "Data".

It does that, but only if the data on "3 Months" is in the same order as the data in "Data", otherwise it doesn't. Clearly what it's doing is matching the current Unique ID with the equivalent Unique ID in the array. Rather than try and match the current Unique ID with all the ID's in the array and make sure it doesn't match any of them.

This is what I have:

```
function contractSearch2() {
  //Get all the sheet names as variables
  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
  var threeMonths = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("3 Months");

  //Get all the expiry dates on the data sheet
  var lastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();
  var endDates = dataSheet.getRange(1, 11, lastRow).getValues();

  //Get today's date
  var today = new Date();

  // Work out when 3 months from now is.
  var threeMonthsOut = new Date(today);
  var CurrentDate = new Date();
  threeMonthsOut.setMonth(CurrentDate.getMonth() + 3);

  // Find months / years that match 3 months out.
  var threeMonthslastRow = threeMonths.getLastRow();
  var CallOffIDs = threeMonths.getRange(1, 4, threeMonthslastRow+1, 1).getValues();
  var test = 0
  var j = 0; 
  //Logger.log(CallOffIDs[1])

  for (var i = 0; i < endDates.length; i++){
    var fDate = new Date(endDates[i][0]);
    // if a date is 3 months in the future
    if (fDate.getMonth() == threeMonthsOut.getMonth() && 
        fDate.getFullYear() == threeMonthsOut.getFullYear()) {
      //get all the row info
      var entry = dataSheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, 44).getValues();

      // Check to see if CallOff ID Exists already
      // Get the CallOff ID from the entry row
      var CallOffCheck = entry[0][3];
      ++j;
      for ( test in CallOffIDs) {
        ++test;
        if (CallOffCheck == CallOffIDs[j]) {
          break;
        } else {
          var threeMonthslastRow2 = threeMonths.getLastRow(); 
          threeMonths.getRange(threeMonthslastRow2 + 1, 1, 1, 44).setValues(entry);
          break;  
        }
      }  
    }
  }
}
```

Since I need to re-order the rows on "3 Months" for another reason and the data on the "Data" sheet is always being updated I'll constantly need to be running the script. Which is why I need it to check all the values.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you have lots of rows to compare each row with, consider hashing the unique IDs in an object, as then you just have to check if that object property exists. For an example of this, review my recent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50286994/9337071

Comment: Hey Dan. Where exactly are you doing a search? I can't seem to get my head around your code. Also, like tehhowch mentioned above, if its a large array, consider creating a unique ID map to help speed up the search lookup.

Comment: You've indeed got some strange indexing pattern going on in your check loop, along with some unused variables. I recommend rewriting the approach, first on paper in pseudo code so you get the details right before you work on the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Array provides four ways of searching:

- `someArray.some` - returns true or false based on whether an item was found or not. lets you write a function to do comparison/matching. This method is available in Google Apps Script.
- `someArray.find` - returns an element from array and lets you write a function to do comparision/matching. if more than one matching element is present, only the first one is returned. This method is **not** available in Google Apps Script.
- `someArray.findIndex` - returns index of an element from array and lets you write a function to do comparision/matching. if more than one matching element is present, only the first one is returned. This method is **not** available in Google Apps Script.
- `someArray.indexOf` - returns -1 if no match is found otherwise returns a 0 based index of matching element. you have to pass a value to search for and can additionally pass the position of array from which to being the search loopup. This method is available in Google Apps Script.

```js
var beasts = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'bison'];

    console.log(beasts.indexOf('bison'));
    // expected output: 1
    
    // start from index 2
    console.log(beasts.indexOf('bison', 2));
    // expected output: 4
    
    console.log(beasts.indexOf('giraffe'));
    // expected output: -1
    
    var foundItem = beasts.find(function(item, arr, index) {
       return item === 'camel'; // my function is searching for camel
    });
    console.log(foundItem);
    // expected output: 'camel'
    
    
    var foundItemIndex = beasts.findIndex(function(item, arr, index) {
       return item === 'camel'; // my function is searching for camel
    });
    console.log(foundItemIndex);
    // expected output: 2
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sadly Google Apps Script (GAS) does not support `Array::find()` or `Array::findIndex()`; GAS is not a full ES6 implementation. And `Array::indexOf()` has been known to be wonky in GAS in certain scenarios. However, GAS does support `Array::some()`. You can refactor your answer to leverage that method instead.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I appreciate the response. I understand how this works, but it's only ever returning -1, I think because my array is 2d. Any ideas how I can fix that?

Comment: You could"flatten" your array using simply .join().split();  which will create a 1D array.