# Checking a folder for a filename, and exporting as PDF if it is not found

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, export-to-pdf

I am quite new to scripting and has attempted this for embarrassingly many hours now, so I hope you can help me.

I have a dashfolder that contains Google Sheets called "X", and I have a pdffolder containing pdfs that are called "X.pdf". I am trying to loop through the names of my dashfiles + ".pdf" to find those which are missing, and finally create its pdf in that same folder. My script, however, loops too many times. I want it to skip the dashfile if a file with the name+".pdf" are already in the pdffolder. Here is my code

```
function createPdf() {
  var pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID")
  var pdfFiles = pdfFolder.getFiles();
  var dashFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('ID');
  var dashFiles = dashFolder.getFiles();
  var pdfNames = [];
  var dashNames = [];

  while (pdfFiles.hasNext()) {
     var currentFile2 = pdfFiles.next();
     var fileName2 = currentFile2.getName();
     pdfNames.push(fileName2);
  }

  while (dashFiles.hasNext()) {
    var currentFile = dashFiles.next();
    var fileName = currentFile.getName();
    dashNames.push(fileName);

    for (p in pdfNames) {
      if((fileName + ".pdf") == pdfNames[p]) {
        Logger.log("YES");
      }
      else {
        var xlsBlob = currentFile.getBlob(); // Blob source of Excel file for conversion
        var xlsFilename = currentFile.getName(); // File name to give to converted file; defaults to same as source file
        pdfFolder.createFile(currentFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF));
        Logger.log("pdf Created");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My real problem stems from the fact that I will have 100+ sheets that needs to be converted to pdf's and that will exceed the 6 minutes limit. So I am trying to build a script that can trigger itself and continue where it left off, skipping sheets that are already in the pdffolder and creating those that are missing.

I might be way over my head here, so I hope someone can give me some hints :-)

Comment: split your task - write a function which handles exporting a given filename to PDF, write a function which stores a list of filenames, write a function that reads that list of filenames, write a function which generates a list of files in a given folder, write a function that returns the elements of list A not in list B, and then write a function that uses all the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrong use loops. Currently you create more pdfs of same sheet, because when you traversating over `dashFiles`, you create PDF one more pdf for each exists PDF.

Change part of code like this:

```
var pdfNames = {}; //Object instead of array

while (pdfFiles.hasNext()) {
   var currentFile2 = pdfFiles.next();
   var fileName2 = currentFile2.getName();
   pdfNames[fileName2] = true; // use PDF name as key for faster searching
}

while (dashFiles.hasNext()) {
  var currentFile = dashFiles.next();
  var fileName = currentFile.getName();

  if(pdfNames[fileName + ".pdf"]) { // is exists pdf?
    Logger.log("YES");
  }
  else {
    var xlsBlob = currentFile.getBlob(); // Blob source of Excel file for conversion
    var xlsFilename = currentFile.getName(); // File name to give to converted file; defaults to same as source file
    pdfFolder.createFile(currentFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF));
    Logger.log("pdf Created");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers!
I devided my tasks, and made everything work from your recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an object of file names with a value of `true`, and then check for the existence of the file name in the object.  If the file name exists, then continue to loop.

```
var pdfNames = {};//Create an object - not an array
pdfNames[fileName2] = true;//Put the file name into the object
if (pdfNames[fileName]) {//Test for file name in the object
```

### Code:

```
function createPdf() {
  var currentFile,fileName,xlsBlob,xlsFilename;
  var pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID")
  var pdfFiles = pdfFolder.getFiles();
  var dashFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('ID');
  var dashFiles = dashFolder.getFiles();
  var pdfNames = {};
  var dashNames = [];

  while (pdfFiles.hasNext()) {
     var currentFile2 = pdfFiles.next();
     var fileName2 = currentFile2.getName();
     pdfNames[fileName2] = true;//Put the file name into the object
  }

  while (dashFiles.hasNext()) {
    currentFile = dashFiles.next();
    fileName = currentFile.getName();
    dashNames.push(fileName);

    if (pdfNames[fileName]) {//The file name was found in the object of pdf files
      Logger.log("YES");
      continue;
    }

    xlsBlob = currentFile.getBlob(); // Blob source of Excel file for conversion
    xlsFilename = currentFile.getName(); // File name to give to converted file; defaults to same as source file
    pdfFolder.createFile(currentFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF));
    Logger.log("pdf Created");
  }

}
```

Original Answer:

Test for the existence of the file name in the pdf array in a different way.

```
pdfNames.indexOf(fileName + ".pdf") !== -1
```

If a value is not found in an array, then `indexOf()` returns minus one.
So, if the return value is not minus one, then a file name was found.  If a file name was found, you don't want a new file created, so continue.

```
function createPdf() {
  var currentFile,fileName,xlsBlob,xlsFilename;
  var pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID")
  var pdfFiles = pdfFolder.getFiles();
  var dashFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('ID');
  var dashFiles = dashFolder.getFiles();
  var pdfNames = [];
  var dashNames = [];

  while (pdfFiles.hasNext()) {
     var currentFile2 = pdfFiles.next();
     var fileName2 = currentFile2.getName();
     pdfNames.push(fileName2);
  }

  while (dashFiles.hasNext()) {
    currentFile = dashFiles.next();
    fileName = currentFile.getName();
    dashNames.push(fileName);

    if (pdfNames.indexOf(fileName + ".pdf") !== -1) {//The file name was found in the array of pdf files
      Logger.log("YES");
      continue;
    }

    xlsBlob = currentFile.getBlob(); // Blob source of Excel file for conversion
    xlsFilename = currentFile.getName(); // File name to give to converted file; defaults to same as source file
    pdfFolder.createFile(currentFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF));
    Logger.log("pdf Created");
  }

}
```

Comment: Array#indexOf is certainly more concise than a full `for` loop over the array, but I don't think it'll be faster because it's still all string equality testing. IMO the best solution is to hash the filenames in an object.

Comment: Hash the file names to what?  `key:"file_Name"`  What is the `key` going to be?

Comment: Use the filenames as the key :) the value can be boring (`true`) or useful (like the id of the file, etc)

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50286994/9337071 for a case where i store useful information